# Weird result with R grImport from Inkscape "trace bitmap"

Tags: r, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to use some svg logos in a plot. Problem is that I have them in `png`, and trace them in Inkscape. All looks good in Inkscape, but when I use the `grImport` package to insert the logo in my R plot, I get some wierd lines going over the image.

This is how I trace the png:

[image]

And this is the code for importing it to my R plot:

```
PostScriptTrace(file = 'myfile.ps')

logo <- readPicture(rgmlFile = 'myfile.ps.xml')

plot(NA, 
  ylim = c(0, 1), 
  axes = FALSE,
  ann = FALSE
)

grid.symbols(logo, 
  x = 0.5, 
  y = 0.5, 
  size = 0.7
)
```

But this is the resulting R plot. Notice the diagonal lines:

[image]

I've tried deleting the nodes in Inkskape that seems to be the origin of the lines (e.g. lower left corner), but the lines just start from a new node when I do.

I've also tried tracing 'edge detection' and 'brightness cutoff' with different thresholds, without success. Also tried random settings in `grImport` R functions `PostScriptTrace` and `readPicture`. But I really don't know what I'm doing...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey maybe you can save the 2 objects out of inscape as 2 files and then read and plot them separately one after another. It looks like that he tries to connect the "m" with the "nya". I think that could be a quick fix.

Comment: have a look at grImport2, IIRC it has better handling of winding rules or whatever that's called

Comment: Thanks @baptiste, after fiddling a bit with the installation it looks promising. No diagonal lines... thanks!